# Global Array doesn't update while inside while loop?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, while-loop

I have an array of structs, inside the while loop I add things to that array, however when I print out the array I get the wrong output?
 (The last element added is printed out n times, n being the number of things I added)

I have googled this and I think it is because a while loop in Bash creates a subshell, not too sure.

Any help would be much appreciated
(please have patience I am only a student!!)

Using Mac OSX mountain lion
Xcode 4 gcc

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

typedef struct{
    char* one;  
    char* two;
} Node;

Node nodes[100];
int count = 0;

void add(char *one,char*two){
    Node newNode = {one,two};
    nodes[count]= newNode;

    printf("one: %s\n",one); 
    printf("two: %s\n",two); 

    count++;
}

void print(){
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        printf("%d : (%s, %s) \n",x,nodes[x].one, nodes[x].two);
}

void check(char **arg)
{
    if(strcmp(*arg, "Add") == 0)
        add(arg[1],arg[2]);
    else if(strcmp(*arg,"print") == 0)
        print();
    else
        printf("Error syntax Enter either: \n Add [item1][item2]\n OR \n print\n");
}

void readandParseInput(char *line,char **arg)
{ 
    if (fgets (line, 512, stdin)!= NULL) {  
        char * pch;
        pch = strtok (line," \n\t");
        int count = 0;
        arg[0] = pch;

        while (pch != NULL)
        {
            count++; 
            pch = strtok (NULL, " \n\t"); 
            arg[count] = pch;
        }
    }else{
        printf("\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i <100; i++){
        nodes[i].one = ".";
        nodes[i].two = ".";
    }

    char  line[512];             /* the input line                 */
    char  *arg[50];              /* the command line argument      */

    while (1) 
    { 
        readandParseInput(line,arg);
        if(arg[0] != NULL)
            check(arg);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: It would help you greatly if you properly indent your code.

Comment: This is nothing to do with while loops in bash and subshells. Your `nodes` is an array of type `Node`, not `Node *`, so you can't do `Node newNode = {one,two};
 nodes[count]= newNode;`.

Comment: How could I add these items to the struct then to array Vicky ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`strtok()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) returns a pointer to different elements within the buffer it was initially passed. This means that all entries in the array will be pointing to different elements of the same buffer, named `line`. You need to make a copy of the pointer returned by `strtok()`:

- use [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), [`strlen()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) and [`strcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy). Or,
- use the non-standard [`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup)

in either case, the memory must be `free()`d when no longer required.

Comment: What needs to be freed? The buffer line?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use the same buffer for all input.

You need to duplicate the strings you put into the structures. Either by using arrays for the strings and `strcpy` into them, or by using `strdup` to allocate new memory for the strings and do the copying in one function.